# How can I change the numbering style of question parts in the exam class?

Tags: numbering, exam

How can I change the numbering style of question parts in the exam class? Currently, I have

```
1.
 (a)
 (b)
```

but I would prefer

```
1.
 (1.1)
 (1.2)
```

I have already tried

```
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\thecurrentpartno.\arabic{partno}}
```

but this results in

```
1.
 (.1)
 (.2)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have read the manual **examdoc.pdf** and the source code **exam.cls** which can be found in **LaTeX2e** distribution. The increment **1, 2, 3, ...** is actually done by the **question** counter. And the increment **a, b, c, ...** is done by the **partno** counter. It can be found in the source code that `\partlabel` is defined to be `(\alpha{partno})`. Thus, we can redefine it as in the code below:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand\partlabel{(\thequestion.\arabic{partno})}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part first
        \part second
    \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A screenshot would and some explanations would improve this answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, it is a good idea :)